# Creating new CRD resource with cluster-admin role

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I created a new service account and a rolebining giving him the role of cluster-admin as follows. I applied a new CRD resource with it and I expected it to fail as the default cluster-admin role can not manage CRD unless a new ClusterRole is created with aggregate-to-admin label, but the CRD was created and I do not understand why.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#aggregated-clusterroles

kubectl create -f new_crd.yaml --as=system:serviceaccount:test-ns:test

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-rolebinding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test
  namespace: test-ns
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: what version of kubernetes are you using?

Comment: kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.3", GitCommit:"1e11e4a2108024935ecfcb2912226cedeafd99df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-10-14T12:50:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.1", GitCommit:"206bcadf021e76c27513500ca24182692aabd17e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-14T07:30:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Hello. By assigning a `cluster-admin` to a serviceAccount you gave **all** the permissions in the cluster (`*`). By that you don't need to create/aggregate any additional clusterroles. Please post the `YAML` definitions of your `ClusterRole` (`cluster-admin`) and the `ServiceAccount` (`test`). Also please clarify which namespace is correct (`secret-ns` in command or `test-ns` in `YAML` definition).

Comment: I did not create the ClusterRole cluster-admin - its default role exists in the cluster. I fixed the sa ns...  I do not understand the purpose of using aggregate-to-admin label -- I thought its purpose is to add rules to cluster-admin but if cluster-admin can do anything in the first place then why it is used?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the part of the last comment:

> I do not understand the purpose of using aggregate-to-admin label -- I thought its purpose is to add rules to cluster-admin but if cluster-admin can do anything in the first place then why it is used?

`aggregate-to-admin` is a `label` used to aggregate `ClusterRoles`. This exact is used to aggregate `ClusterRoles` to an **`admin`** `ClusterRole`.

> A side note!
>
> `cluster-admin` and `admin` are two separate `ClusterRoles`.

I will include the example of aggregating `ClusterRoles` with an explanation below.

You can read in the official Kubernetes documentation:

| Default ClusterRole | Default ClusterRoleBinding | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cluster-admin | system:masters group | Allows super-user access to perform any action on any resource. When used in a ClusterRoleBinding, it gives full control over every resource in the cluster and in all namespaces. When used in a RoleBinding, it gives full control over every resource in the role binding's namespace, including the namespace itself. |
| admin | None | Allows admin access, intended to be granted within a namespace using a RoleBinding. If used in a RoleBinding, allows read/write access to most resources in a namespace, including the ability to create roles and role bindings within the namespace. This role does not allow write access to resource quota or to the namespace itself. |
|  |  |  |

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Access authn authz: RBAC: User facing roles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles)*

---

#### Using aggregated `ClusterRoles`

The principle behind aggregated `Clusterroles` is to have one `ClusterRole` that have multiple other `ClusterRoles` aggregated to it.

Let's assume that:

- A `ClusterRole`: `aggregated-clusterrole` will be aggregating two other `ClusterRoles` that will have needed permissions on some actions.
- A `ClusterRole`: `clusterrole-one` will be used to add some permissions to `aggregated-clusterrole`
- A `ClusterRole`: `clusterrole-two` will be used to add some permissions to `aggregated-clusterrole`

An example of such setup could be implemented by `YAML` definitions like below:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: aggregated-clusterrole
aggregationRule:
  clusterRoleSelectors:
  - matchLabels:
      rbac.example.com/put-here-any-label-name: "true" # <-- IMPORTANT
rules: []
```

Above definition will be aggregating `ClusterRoles` created with a `label`:

- `rbac.example.com/put-here-any-label-name: "true"`

Describing this `ClusterRole` without aggregating any `ClusterRoles` with previously mentioned `label`:

- `$ kubectl describe clusterrole aggregated-clusterrole`

```sh
Name:         aggregated-clusterrole
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources  Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------  -----------------  --------------  -----
```

Two `ClusterRoles` that will be used are the following:

`clusterrole-one.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: clusterrole-one
  labels:
    rbac.example.com/put-here-any-label-name: "true" # <-- IMPORTANT
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

`clusterrole-two.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: clusterrole-two
  labels:
    rbac.example.com/put-here-any-label-name: "true" # <-- IMPORTANT
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["create", "delete"]
```

After applying above definitions, you can check if `aggregated-clusterrole` have permissions used in `clusterrole-one` and `clusterrole-two`:

- `$ kubectl describe clusterrole aggregated-clusterrole`

```sh
Name:         aggregated-clusterrole
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources  Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------  -----------------  --------------  -----
  services   []                 []              [create delete]
  pods       []                 []              [get list watch]
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Access authn authz: RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)*